# passing filter variables through the url and retaining them through a redirect

Tags: django

I have 2 issues:

1. I have a redirect which returns to the same template, there is a filter applied which passes parameters like so: `http://localhost:99/depot/container/11/?area_easting=99&area_northing=&context_number=123&sample_number=&sample_type=organic`. When I redirect to the same template the parameters are lost (as expected) how do I redirect and retain this parameters? I also expect I will need a 'refresh query button.
2. In the template I can pass operation, and the sample_id, but not the container_id. This comes from a m2m `samples = models.ManyToManyField('Sample', through='ContainerSamples')`, how do I pass this value in the url - related to point 1.

My code

```
<a href="{ url 'depot:change_container'  operation='add' pk=sample.container.container_id fk=sample.sample_id }" class="badge badge-primary" role="button">
      <<
    </a>

# urls.py
path('container/<int:container_id>/', views.detailcontainer, name='detailcontainer'),

# views.py
def detailcontainer(request, container_id):
    container = get_object_or_404(Container, pk=container_id)
    samples = container.samples.all()
    container_contents = container.samples.all()
    unassigned_samples = Sample.objects.all()[:10]
    unassigned_samples2 = Sample.objects.all()

    qs = Sample.objects.all()
    easting_query = request.GET.get('area_easting')
    northing_query = request.GET.get('area_northing')
    context_query = request.GET.get('context_number')
    sample_number_query = request.GET.get('sample_number')
    sample_type_query = request.GET.get('sample_type')

    if easting_query != '' and easting_query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(area_easting__icontains=easting_query)
    if northing_query != '' and northing_query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(area_northing__icontains=northing_query)
    if context_query != '' and context_query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(context_number__icontains=context_query)
    if sample_number_query != '' and sample_number_query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(sample_number__icontains=sample_number_query)
    if sample_type_query != '' and sample_type_query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(sample_type__icontains=sample_type_query)

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'container':container,
        'container_contents': container_contents,
        'unassigned_samples': unassigned_samples,
    }
    return render(request, 'container/detailcontainer.html', context)

# template
      {% for sample in queryset %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{ url 'depot:change_container'  operation='add' pk=sample.container.container_id fk=sample.sample_id }" class="badge badge-primary" role="button">
          <<
        </a></td>
        <td>{{ sample.sample_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ sample.samples.container.container_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ sample.area_easting }}.{{ sample.area_northing }}.{{ sample.context_number }}.{{ sample.sample_number }}</td>

        <td>
  {{ sample.sample_type }}
        </td>

        <td>{{ sample.taken_by }}</td>

      </tr>
      {% empty %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">No data</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

EDIT

The operation is handled through this code:

```
def change_container(request, operation, pk='', fk=''):
    container = Container.objects.get(pk=pk)
    sample = Sample.objects.get(pk=fk)

    if operation == 'add':
        ContainerSamples.add_to_container(container, sample)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        ContainerSamples.remove_from_container(container, sample)
    # return redirect('depot:allcontainer')

    return redirect('depot:detailcontainer', container_id=pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url path just accept a `container_id` so you won't be able to pass those values you want as url params. Either you need to change your url path or keep passing them as query strings, which I believe that's what you want.

To pass them as query strings, you need to include all the `request.GET.get('qs')` you're collecting in your view to your context and they'll be available on the template.

```
    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'container':container,
        'container_contents': container_contents,
        'unassigned_samples': unassigned_samples,
        'easting_query': easting_query,
        'northing_query': northing_query,
        'context_query': context_query,
        'sample_number_query': sample_number_query,
        'sample_type_query': sample_type_query
    }
```

Then on your template you pass them in the url tag.

`<td><a href="{% url 'depot:change_container' container.container_id %}?operation=add&foo=bar&blabla=123" class="badge badge-primary" role="button">`

Comment: Thank you,adding it to the `operation` would affect the associated functionality (see edit). So I think I need a url tag like `easting_query= sample.area_easting` 

Then to `def change_container(request, operation, pk='', fk=''):` add `area_easting=''` etc.

And `easting_query = request.GET.get('area_easting')`

Followed by `if easting_query != '' and easting_query is not None:
        unassigned_samples = unassigned_samples.filter(area_easting__icontains=easting_query)`

Is that close?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you exactly want. Answering your first question on your post: To keep the filters every time you are redirected, you need to pass them to the template by sending them on the context.

Comment: I've got a temporary solution, setting the queryset to empty if the filter is empty, so on reload the query has to be entered again. I'll try to digest your answer, been a long week.